# WebAPI - Log binding information at MessageHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to log (not Trace) all requests and responses from webAPI (v1) and store the information in DB.

I thought that the most appropriate place to do it is via a `MessageHandler`.

So  :

```
public class LogRequestAndResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override   Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        return  base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    var MyRequest = request;
                    var MyResponse = task.Result;
                    var responseBody = task.Result.Content;

                    //log db....

                    return task.Result;
                }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Please notice that I'm reading the `request` and `response` *after* the `SendAsync` ( in a continuation) because I want a *single* write to DB.

**But:**

I thought to myself : *"it would be nice if I could extract the method binding information at the same place (in the MessageHandler)"*

For example  , consider this code :

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetGraph")]
public HttpResponseMessage BlaBla(string Member_ID, int DateDiff)
{
   //...
}
```

And this request :

```
http://es.com/api/claims/GetGraph?Member_ID=123&DateDiff=5&NotExists=2
```

**Question:**

Is it possible(and how) to extract something like this :

- User sent match-able `Member_ID` with value `123`
- User sent match-able `DateDiff` with value `5`
- User sent **non**-match-able `NotExists` with value `2`

At **this** stage :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about using a message handler for logging the raw request and response but then were you able to log the request body using the code above? If you actually bind the body to an action method parameter, parameter binding would actually read and empty the request body stream. So, I don't think your idea of logging the request body in task continuation will work.

Logging data about binding in a message handler is complicated and depends a lot on your action methods.  Message handler request processing runs before model binding and when the response processing part runs, the notion of models do not exist, since serialization is already done. BTW, take a look at my blog post for detecting extra fields in the request, when you are using JSON payload.

http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/detecting-extra-fields-in-asp-net-web-api-request/

You can possibly write an action filter to look at the extra fields from the model, as mentioned in that post and store that info in request dictionary (`Request.Properties`) and pick that up later in the message handler and write to database. It is not straight forward though.

Alternatively, look at the built-in tracer to see if it is helpful.